# Permalink Trouble with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom post type called "work" and it has a taxonomy called "categories". Currently "/work" and "/work/category_slug/work_slug" works great. However "/work/category_slug" does not. I get a 404 page. Any ideas what I can do?

```
register_post_type('work', array(
'label' => 'Work',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'work', 'with_front' => true),
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes'),
'taxonomies' => array('categories'),
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Work',
  'singular_name' => 'work',
  'menu_name' => 'Work',
  'add_new' => 'Add New',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Item',
  'edit' => 'Edit ',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
  'new_item' => 'New Item',
  'view' => 'View',
  'view_item' => 'View Item',
  'search_items' => 'Search Items',
  'not_found' => 'No Work Items Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Work Items found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Work Item',
)
) ); 


register_taxonomy( 'categories',array (
   0 => 'work',
),
array( 'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Categories',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'labels' => array (
  'search_items' => 'Category',
  'popular_items' => '',
  'all_items' => '',
  'parent_item' => '',
  'parent_item_colon' => '',
  'edit_item' => '',
  'update_item' => '',
  'add_new_item' => '',
  'new_item_name' => '',
  'separate_items_with_commas' => '',
  'add_or_remove_items' => '',
  'choose_from_most_used' => '',
)
) );
```

Comment: show us the code you use to register the taxonomy and post type.

Comment: Alright added the code.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "`categories/category_slug`" not "`work/category_slug`" for the category archieve page

Comment: I've actually had it working the way I described, but I set it up over a year ago and can't remember what I did. Having "categories" in the url is just so ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php.

```
// Include Custom Post Types on Tags and Categories Archive Pages

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag() || is_taxonomy()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
if($post_type)
  $post_type = $post_type;
 else
 $post_type = array('work', 'post'); // replace cpt to your custom post type
 $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
 return $query;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok.. You can remove 

|| is_tag()

so it doesn't add CPT to tag archive page.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. I'm not using the default category taxonomy I created my own so would is_category still be relevant?

Comment: @paper_robots Just add is_taxonomy into this function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy. Check updated code.